# JS code popping up error

Tags: javascript

I got this below code from Google for E-mail validation in my js file.

```
function validateEmail(thefield) 
{  
   alert ('This is the 1st step');  
   var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;  
   alert ('This is the 2nd step');  **after this i am getting error in explorer**  
   var address = document.elements[thefield].value;   
   alert ('going into if loop' + address.value);  
   if(reg.test(address) == false)  
   {  
    alert('Invalid Email Address');   
      return false;   
   }  
}
```

Please let me know what modifications are required in this to make it work??

HTML code:

```
<form action="pageserver" method="post" id="inputForm" target="_parent" onsubmit="return(onSubmit());">
 <input type="text" value=" " name="MIR-CLI-CNTCT-ID-TXT-T[1]" stype="Text" maxlength="50" onfocus="enterField(this)" onblur="validateEmail(this)" size="50" />
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're using? Having no context available, my guess is that the problem lies with the `document.elements[thefield].value` part, but there's really no way for me to tell.

Comment: Also: [Comparing E-mail Address Validating Regular Expressions](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php)

Comment: in html, its done as                                                                <form action="pageserver" method="post" id="inputForm" target="_parent" onsubmit="return(onSubmit());">                                                                                                                               <input type="text" value=" " name="MIR-CLI-CNTCT-ID-TXT-T[1]" stype="Text" maxlength="50" onfocus="enterField(this)" onblur="validateEmail(this)" size="50" />

Answer (score 0):

Thansk sdleihssirhc.

I could find out the error.... and fix it...

the line was having erros, **var address = document.elements[thefield].value;**

I removed the vairable which was passed in the function and just placed the same variable directly in the required field....

**var address = document.all[email].value;**

Comment: That's very very bad thing as it's IE only. Over half the people will get errors from your code, as IE is going down. Add ID to the textbox like this: `<input type="text" id="email" ... />` then have such line instead: `var address = document.getElementById("email").value;` this will work on all browsers.